# Mysterious number icon next to file name in PhpStorm

Tags: php, editor, phpstorm

I accidentally pushed a hotkey in PhpStorm, and now there is a little number icon next to one of my file names.

What does this mean, and how can I remove it?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Why is this closed? The post *directly involves a tool used primarily for programming*, doesn't it?

Comment: This is not off-topic

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> What does this mean

That's a **Bookmark with Mnemonic** -- basically, a numbered bookmark that can be quickly accessed from anywhere using that mnemonic as a key.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/navigating-with-bookmarks.html?search=bookmarks

> and how can I remove it

Same way how you set it up. Few ways actually:

1. Bring *Bookmarks screen* in and remove any unwanted bookmark from there: `Navigate | Bookmarks | Show Bookmarks` (<kbd>Shift + F11</kbd> using Default keymap on Linux/Windows)
2. Select that file in Project View panel and while focus is still there activate `Navigate | Bookmarks | Toggle Bookmark with Mnemonic` (<kbd>Ctrl + F11</kbd> using Default keymap on Linux/Windows)