# Mysterious checked icon in PhpStorm

Tags: phpunit, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, phpcodesniffer

Please what is a icon in my project ? is it from CodeSniffer OR PHPUnit ?
Thanks a lot!

[image: PhpStorm icon]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bookmark -- you have bookmarked a file and not just a specific line.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40653696/783119
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/38540770/783119

---

Just focus the file in the Project View panel and press the same shortcut again (<kbd>F11</kbd> on Windows). https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2020.1/navigating-through-the-source-code.html

Or just go to `Favorites panel | Bookmarks node` or just straight via Boormarks popup (`Navigate | Bookmarks | Show Bookmarks` -- <kbd>Shift + F11</kbd>) and remove it there.

**Favorites | Bookmarks node** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/managing-your-project-favorites.html):

[image]

**Show Bookmarks popup** (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/bookmarks-dialog.html):

[image]